# Why this shows two flash messages but the other one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is view

```
<%= '<br /><br />' if flash %>
<% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
  <div class="alert alert-<%= name == :notice ? "success" : name.to_s %>">
    <a class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&#215;</a>
    <%= content_tag :div, msg.html_safe, :id => "flash_#{name}" if msg.is_a?(String) %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<%= yield %>
```

This code below shows only one flash message("Deleted") on the top of the screen when after I deleted a record. Then that's how I want.

```
def update

    if params[:destroy]

        if current_user.id == @code.user_id
            @code.destroy
            flash[:notice] = "Deleted"
        else
            flash[:notice] = "You don't have permission to edit"
        end

        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to community_codes_url }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end

    else

        respond_to do |format|
            if @code.update_attributes(params[:code])
                format.html { redirect_to community_code_path(@community.community_name, @code), notice: 'Updated' }
                format.json { head :no_content }
            else
                format.html { render action: "edit" }
                format.json { render json: @code.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
            end
        end

    end

end
```

But this code below is messing up this rule, and I'm totally confused:(

If I create new record, it should show just one flash message like previous one. Then it has tweet button in it.

This flash doesn't not contain only string but also contains `html` and `javascript` within flash message.
I don't think it matters whether if there will be 2 flash messages or not:(

How can I show only one flash message?

```
def create      

    @code = @community.codes.build (params[:code]) 
    @code.user_id = current_user.id

    respond_to do |format|
        if @code.save       
            tag_strings = @community.tags.join(", ") + "," if @community.tags
            flash[:notice] = '<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-hashtags="' + tag_strings + 'tags here!">Tweet</a><script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>You can tweet if you click this button'

            format.html { redirect_to community_code_path(@community.community_name, @code) }
            format.json { render json: [@community, @code], status: :created, location: @code }
        else
            format.html { render action: "new" }
            format.json { render json: @code.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In the one that only shows one message, you're writing to the `notice` key of the `flash` hash, then writing to that same key *again,* thereby overwriting it.  In the one that shows two messages, you're writing to the `notice` key once, and the `error` key once, resulting in two keys.  Then, the flash mechanism displays both.  Based on the flash display mechanisms you're using, they might appear in different colors, since they're two different 'levels' of problem.

If you want to only display one, you could keep writing to the same key of the `flash` hash.

Comment: thanks for explanation. But I don't get it. Could you show me with code what to fix??

Comment: In the one that only shows one message, it looks that I'm writing to the `notice` key of the `flash` hash only once. not more than that:(

Comment: You can forget about `error` key because it always won't match with that if statement condition, so it wont be fired anyway. There should be another problem:(

Comment: If you're positive that it's dead code,, then you should remove it from your problem statement.  We can't tell that it's dead code by *inspection*, after all...

Comment: True. I've just took it off